# How to block fields from being available when pressing the tab key

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have transformed some fields on my data entry form using code so that the user needs to update them by clicking them with the mouse.  Unfortunately, I do not understand how to remove them from the tab order field so that the user with the tab key toggles only through the fields which are not updated by mouse point and clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the Tab Stop property of the various controls. For details see

[Remove a control from the tab order](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/set-the-tab-order-for-controls-HA010285217.aspx#BM2)

Comment: you saved me again Gord. Cheers